# Prevent form submition in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, typescript

I have a normal form with a couple of checkboxes. When I change a checkbox I'd like the checkbox to submit the form. The form itself will then handle the submission, in this case prevent the submission to do some other stuff but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I know how to prevent the submission in jQuery but I want to use vanilla javascript in this case.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Below you'll find my code:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('form.filter-form input[type="checkbox"]')
  .forEach((formElement: HTMLInputElement) => {
    formElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
      formElement.form.submit();
    });
  });

document.querySelector('form.filter-form')
  .addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('this should prevent the form from submitting but doesnt.');
  });
```

```html
<form action="#" class="filter-form">
  <input type="checkbox" name="var[]" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="var[]" value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="var[]" value="3" />
</form>
```

Comment: Let me try to understand...you want the checkbox, on change, to submit the form...but actually you don't want to submit the form and do something else instead?

Comment: You need a submit button to submit the form, where is the button, prevent default only prevents the action of submit buttons

Comment: @blacksheep That is not really accurate. For example submitting by keyboard or triggered event

Comment: @charlietfl i don't need any help yet, why don't you just help the person asking the question.

Comment: @blacksheep I did already with a working solution that requires no buttons

Comment: cool 

Comment: By the way, that code has no sense, trigger a form submit with the checkbox but cancel the submit event in the form. Just don't do it

Comment: I don't need a submit button and I want the functionality of the checkboxes and form submission separated. (separation of concerns and sfuff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`requestSubmit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit) instead of `submit()`.

From [`submit()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit):

> No submit event is raised. In particular, the form's onsubmit event
> handler is not run.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('form.filter-form input[type="checkbox"]')
  .forEach((formElement) => {
    formElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
      formElement.form.requestSubmit();
                 
    });
  });

document.querySelector('form.filter-form')
  .addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('this should prevent the form from submitting but doesnt.');
  });
```

```html
<form action="#" class="filter-form">
  <input type="checkbox" name="var[]" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="var[]" value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="var[]" value="3" />
</form>
```